# Get value from childNode inside container div

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function(e){
  var newNode = $('#origin').clone();
  $('#container').append(newNode);
  for(var i=0; i<$('#container').children().length; i++)
   $('#result').append($('#container').children(i).html()+"<br>");
});
```

```html
<html>
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js'></script>
<body>
<span id='origin' my-data='somedata'>Hello</span>
<div id='container'>
  <span emoji-data='mmm'>a</span>
  <span>b</span>
  <span>
    <span>b1</span>
    <span>b2</span>
  </span>
  <span>c</span>
</div>
<p></p>
<b>Content inside every nodes:</b>
<div id='result'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Expected result is: a, b, ....
But in this, I got only a value. How to fix it? Thank you!

Comment: Try text instead html $('#result').append($('#container').children(i).text()+"<br>");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't pass a number to the `children` function, you pass a selector if you want to limit your search to only certain elements. For example, if you wanted only `<span>` elements, you'd use `$("#container").children("span")`.

Instead of using a `for` loop, you want to use the [`each` function](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) on the children, and append their content using a callback function:

```js
$(document).ready(function(e){
  var newNode = $('#origin').clone();
  $('#container').append(newNode);
  $('#container').children().each(function(el) {
    $('#result').append($(this).html()+"<br>");
  });
});
```

```html
<html>
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js'></script>
<body>
<span id='origin' my-data='somedata'>Hello</span>
<div id='container'>
  <span emoji-data='mmm'>a</span>
  <span>b</span>
  <span>
    <span>b1</span>
    <span>b2</span>
  </span>
  <span>c</span>
</div>
<p></p>
<b>Content inside every nodes:</b>
<div id='result'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! Done <3